# Unexpected results using sprintf and %g to convert double to string

Tags: c++, printf

When I use MBCS and msvcr120.dll (12.0.40660.0) I get unexpected results when using %g with sprintf to convert a double to a string.  The documentation for %g says default precision will be 6.  Why am I seeing the results below?

```
{
    double d = 1234567.00;
    char buf[100];

    sprintf_s(buf, sizeof(buf), "%g", d);

    //result is 1.23457e+006
}
```

Why is the result `1.23457e+006` instead of `1.23456e+006`? Does truncation occur after 6 digits?

Comment: `1.23457` has 6 digits. The power of ten doesn't count towards significant digits. Please share what you expect the output to be.

Comment: `1.23457e+006` has six *significant* digits (the ones before the 'e') which is what the precision is about.

Comment: Yes, it states that. [It also states](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) that if condition "P > X ≥ −4" (where P is precision; 6 if unspecified, and X is the exponent of the number if printed with E style) is not satisified (in your case it's 6 > 6 ≥ −4 = not satisfied), it will be printed with E style - scientific notation, which is exactly, what's done in your case. What is wrong, exactly?

Comment: Why is the result 1.23457e+006 instead of 1.23456e+006?  Does truncation occur after 6 digits?

Comment: ah, so it rounds to six digits?

Comment: @user1707438 It's just rounding up the 6.

Comment: `1.234567e+006` has a percision of 7, to get to 6 you need to round so the end `7` disappears and the `6` becomes a `7`.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance.  I missed the fact that it will be rounded to six digits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why am I seeing the results below?

This is how the C standard specifies the format in section [Formatted input/output functions] (C++ delegates the specification):

> f,F
>
> A **double** argument representing a floating-point number is converted to decimal notation in style [−]ddd.ddd, where the number of digits after the decimal-point character is equal to the precision specification. If the precision is missing, it is taken as 6; if the precision is zero and the **#** flag is not specified, no decimal-point character appears. If a decimal-point character appears, at least one digit appears before it. The value is rounded to the appropriate number of digits.
>
> e,E
>
> A **double** argument representing a floating-point number is converted in the style [-]d.ddde±dd, where there is one digit (which is nonzero if the argument is nonzero) before the decimal-point character and the number of digits after it is equal to the precision; if the precision is missing, it is taken as 6; if the precision is zero and the **#** flag is not specified, no decimal-point character appears. The value is rounded to the appropriate number of digits. The **E** conversion specifier produces a number with **E** instead of **e** introducing the exponent. The exponent always contains at least two digits, and only as many more digits as necessary to represent the exponent. If the value is zero, the exponent is zero.
>
> A **double** argument representing an infinity is converted in one of the styles **[-]inf** or **[-]infinity** - which style is implementation-defined. A double argument representing a NaN is converted in one of the styles **[-]nan* or **[-nan]**(n-char-sequence) - which style, and the meaning of any n-char-sequence, is implementation-defined. The F conversion specifier produces **INF**,**INFINITY**, or **NAN** instead of **inf**,**infinity** ,or **nan**, respectively.
>
> g,G
>
> A **double** argument representing a floating-point number is converted in style **f** or **e** (or in style **F** or **E** in the case of **G** conversion specifier), depending on the value converted and the precision. Let `P` equal the precision if nonzero, 6 if the precision is omitted, or 1 if the precision is zero. Then, if a conversion with style **E** would have an exponent of `X`:
>
> - if `P > X ≥ -4`, the conversion is with style **f** (or **F**) and precision `P - (X + 1)`.
> - otherwise, the conversion is with style **e** (or **E**) and precision `P - 1`.

---

> Why is the result 1.23457e+006 instead of 1.23456e+006?

Because the default precision is 6, and the value is rounded.

The default rounding mode (according to IEEE 754) is "round to nearest and ties to even". The next and previous round values of 1.234567 are 1.23457 and 1.23456. 1.23457 is nearer, so 1.234567 rounds to 1.23457.